# Displaying Maya Mesh XML in browser

Tags: graphics, canvas, mesh, maya

I have a Mesh file (XML format) created in Maya.
I would like to display it in the browser with some additional options for the user, like rotating an zooming in and out.

What should be the best and easy method to do so?
(SilverLight, HTML5/JS/Canvas, Flesh)

I would really like to try HTML5/Canvas - is there any libraries that know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I would really like to try
>   HTML5/Canvas - is there any libraries
>   that know how to do it?

You can visit this site [learningwebgl](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/)

There are a lot of lessons and demos. On the right side there is a list of frameworks.
But you need browser support for webgl...

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to export your file in Collada/DAE format (which is basically XML), there are some online WebGL framework demos that show that a DAE file can be displayed the way you wish.

The frameworks that I've seen this for are [GLGE](http://www.glge.org/) and [SpiderGL](http://spidergl.org/).

(WebGL is the 3D version of HTML5/Canvas.)

Answer (score 0):

you can export your maya scene with http://www.inka3d.com and then manipulate it with javascript